# How to Get the Probability value of all the entity mentions

Tags: stanford-nlp

Lets consider this text:

> *"John Joseph lives in America. He works in federal government"*

I am getting the following entity mentions for this text:

1. `John Joseph`
2. `America`
3. `He`
4. `Federal government`

Now I am trying to get the probability value for each entity mentions. When I look at the `Java APIs`, I noticed we can get the probability value for each tokens (John, Joseph, America, He, Federal & Government).

But how do we get the probability value of "John Joseph" & "Federal Government" (More than one token)? Is there any Java API available to get this value?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being stupid, but if you know how to get individual probabilities, sure one could simply add the two probabilities together to find the combined probability?

Comment: If John is identified as **PERSON** & Joseph is identified as **OTHER** entity type, then how do we combine the probability ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are going to add a new feature in Stanford CoreNLP 3.9.2 that attaches the minimal token-label probability for the entity.  We won't provide any score for anything derived via rules though, because it's not clear what confidence would be appropriate.  So for instance "Joe Smith" might get the probability that the "Joe" token has for PERSON.  This seems like a reasonable heuristic.

We aim for this new release to be out before the end of the month!  I'll update this answer with more details upon release.